# How can i publish my node on network using sawtooth hyperledger application

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

How can I publish my node on network using sawtooth hyperledger-sawtooth application

I am new on sawtooth try to use below git repro

[git repro for this is](https://github.com/hyperledger/education.git)
I have found some links regarding this 
https://lists.hyperledger.org/pipermail/hyperledger-stl/2018-January/000146.html

here is course guide for sawtooth

[Hyperledger courseguidelink](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:LinuxFoundationX+LFS171x+3T2017/courseware/9faeeb6df17c4d25a205c965473925e5/016a2cd813884e32a0c3056c472d39b1/?child=first)

already ask a question on GitHub
https://github.com/hyperledger/education/issues/18

Here is code i am using 
https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/sawtooth-material/sawtooth-tuna

Comment: Please put the code you are trying in your post, as the repo could change.

Comment: This is code i am working
https://github.com/hyperledger/education/tree/master/LFS171x/sawtooth-material/sawtooth-tuna

Comment: the code needs to be in the question

Comment: Thanks i have added in question

Comment: Are you running sawtooth components in docker? If so, there are "compose" files in sawtooth-core/docker/compose directory that starts all the necessary components. If you want to add your TP to the mix you have to create a docker image of it and add the appropriate statements to one of the *.yaml compose files.

Comment: no frank i am not using docker images right now, but I figure it out how to use that

Answer (score 3):

If we wish to connect two nodes using the file you only need the following need to use `validator.toml`, inside `/etc/sawtooth`

If this file is not there then we need to create that:

```
$ cd /etc/sawtooth
$ sudo touch validator.toml
```

Remember to execute below line to run the validator with sawtooth:

```
$ sudo chown root:sawtooth validator.toml
```

Sample `validator.toml` file contents:

```
# Set the network and component endpoints
bind = [
 "network:tcp://127.0.0.1:8800",
 "component:tcp://127.0.0.1:4004"
]
# The type of peering approach the validator should take
peering = "static"
# Advertised network endpoint
endpoint = "tcp://127.0.0.1:8800"
# Uris to initially connect to the validator network
seeds = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:8801"]
# A list of peers to attempt to connect to
peers = ["tcp://127.0.0.1:8801"]
```